# Error in QBE on SpagoBI Server

Tags: business-intelligence

I'm new to SpagoBI so please excuse my ignorance. I have configured SpagoBI Studio and Server on Windows 7. I have configured a SQL Server 2005 data source using JDBC but when I try to create a data set using QBE, on a datamart I created in Studio I get the following error:

An unexpected error occured while executing dataset: Incorrect syntax near '`'.

I have tried what was explained here (http://www.spagoworld.org/jforum/posts/list/1557.page) but this hasn't fixed the issue. I've also tried both 3.6 and 4.0 but still get this error.  Any help anyone can provide would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this work.  The file path that needs to be edited (from the link above) is located in \webapps\SpagoBI\WEB-INF\lib, not \webapps\SpagoBIQbeEngine\WEB-INF\lib